# Http Angular JS took a long time to get response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am still learning AngularJS, and I am going to make a front page authentication. So what these snippet code do? 1st of all, I need to make identifier which consists of 10 random strings and number followed by timestamp (let's name them identifier for the time being). Next, I store the identifier in the cookies. And then, I make HTTP Get request to obtain public key for encryption by sending identifier taken from cookies to a certain website. The problem is, why is the process of obtaining public key took a long time. Usually, AngularJS is pretty quick. But somehow, this took more than 5 seconds most of the time. Can you please help me to find out the problem? Much appreciated.

By the way, these are my code snippets

**app.js**

```
var routeApp = angular.module('HondaSurabayaCenter', ['ngRoute', 'ngCookies']);

routeApp.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', '$http', function($scope, $cookies, $cookieStore, $http) {
function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}
var starttime = performance.now();
var randomText = makeid();
var timestamp = Date.now();
var cookie_name1 = "identifier";
$cookies.put(cookie_name1, randomText+timestamp);
console.log("identifier : "+$cookies.get(cookie_name1));
var data = {identifier: $cookies.get(cookie_name1)};
}]);

routeApp.controller('HttpServiceController', ['$cookies', '$http', function($cookies, $http) {

$http.get('http://app.hondaeastjava.com/api/honda/user/keys', {params: {identifier: $cookies.get('identifier')}, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).
    then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log("Data submitted successfully");
        console.log(response.data);
        $cookies.put("publickey", response.data.result.publickey);

        var endtime = performance.now();
        console.log("Time took to do http get : "+(endtime-starttime));
    }, function errorCallback(response){
        console.log("Service not found");
    })
}]);
```

Comment: I would expect that most of the time is server side and likely nothing you can fix in JavaScript/AngularJS

Comment: Check the Network tab in Developer Console for any delays and timing issues

Comment: @AlekseySolovey apparently it also has some issues with CORB. Could it be that  Allow-Control-Allow-Origin extension is the one that slowing it down?